# Ocaml - Path between two nodes (How to debug)

Tags: graph, path, ocaml

I need to make an algorithm to solve this problem using a **BFS** :
given an oriented weighted graph, a start node, a stop node, and a integer K, say if exist a path between start and stop with wight at least k.

So, first I declared my **weighted oriented graph type**, a list of triples:

```
 type 'a graph = Gr of ('a * 'a * 'a) list;;

 let grafo1 =  Gr [(1,3,2);(1,1,5);(2,2,3);(5,5,3);(5,4,6);(3,1,6);(3,7,4);(6,2,7);(4,4,6)];;
```

In `(x,y,z)`, `x` is the starting node, `y` the edge weight and `z` the arrive node.

Then I made a **`succ`** function:

```
let succ (Gr arcs) n=
     let rec aux = function
         [] -> []
         | (x,y,z):: rest ->
           if n = x then z::(aux rest)
           else aux rest 
    in aux arcs;;
```

This function give me the successors of a node as oputput, so:

```
succ grafo1 1
```

gives me

```
   int list = [2; 5]
```

as output.

In the end, I made this **`bf_path`** function, it's a modified BFS that can find a path between 2 nodes (otherwise it raises an exception) and it takes 3 inputs: a graph, a predicate and a starting node

```
 let bf_path g p start =  
       let rec aux visited = function  
           [] -> raise Not_found  
           | x::rest -> if List.mem x visited then aux visited rest  
              else if p x then [x]  
              else try aux (x::visited) rest  
                with Not_found ->  
                  x:: aux (x::visited) (succ g x)  
       in aux [] [start];;
```

The predicate specifies the condition, so the call:

```
  bf_path grafo1 ((=)7)1
```

gives me `int list = [1; 5; 6; 7]` as output, the path between nodes 1 and 7.

Now, I can find a path but I need to find a path with *at least* weight `K`, so I made a little function that takes a list of triples as input and it sum the weight value:

```
let rec tot = function
   [] -> 0
   |(v,c,p)::t -> c + (tot t);;
```

So, call and output:

```
  tot [(2,2,3);(4,5,6);(8,9,0)]

   - : int = 16
```

I thought all I needed was to add the condition inside the function so I made this function where I add an int `K` as input and a condition: `(tot path >= k)`

```
   let bf_path_final g p start k =  
      let rec aux visited = function  
        [] -> raise Not_found  
        | x::rest -> if List.mem x visited then aux visited rest  
            else if p x then 
               if (tot [x]) >= k then [x]
               else aux visited rest 
            else try aux (x::visited) rest  
              with Not_found ->  
                x:: aux (x::visited) (succ g x)  
      in aux [] [start];;
```

The function compiles without problem:

```
   val bf_path_final : ('a * int * 'b) graph -> 
  ('a * int * 'b -> bool) -> 'a * int * 'b -> int -> ('a * int * 'b) list = <fun>
```

However, I get an **error** when I try to call it:

```
bf_path_final grafo1 ((=)4)1,13;;
              ^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type int graph_w
       but an expression was expected of type ('a * int * 'b) graph_w
```

So, is the function wrong or do I have to call it on another way?

**Another solution** was to give the function **bf_path** output (the path) as input to my **tot** function, but my output is a list of int, not a list of triples, so i tried to convert my first function to give an output of triplees:

(ex: instead of `[1;5;6;7]` it should give `[(1,1,5);(5,4,6);(6,2,7)]`)

```
let bf_path_tr g p start =  
    let rec aux visited = function  
         [] -> raise Not_found  
         | (x,y,z)::rest -> if List.mem x visited then aux visited rest  
            else if p x then [(x,y,z)]  
            else try aux (x::visited) rest  
              with Not_found ->  
                 (x,y,z):: aux (x::visited) (succ_w g (x,y,z))  
    in aux [] [start];;
```

Same results, the function is compiled

```
 val bf_path_tr :
  ('a * 'b * 'c) graph ->
  ('a -> bool) -> 'a * 'b * 'c -> ('a * 'b * 'c) list = <fun>
```

but I get the same error:

```
bf_path_tr grafo1 ((=)7)2

  Characters 11-18:
  bf_path_tr grafo1 ((=)7)2;;
             ^^^^^^
  Error: This expression has type int graph
     but an expression was expected of type ('a * 'b * 'c) graph
```

Any ideas to solve at least one of these two problems?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug this sort of thing is to start adding explicit type annotations everywhere, till you find the place where your expectations don't match the inferred type.

```
let bf_path_final (g : int graph) (p : int -> bool) (start : int) (k : int) =   
  let rec aux (visited : int list) = function  
      [] -> raise Not_found  
    | x::rest -> if List.mem x visited then aux visited rest  
      else if p x then ( 
        if (tot [x]) >= k then [x] 
        else aux visited rest )
      else try aux (x::visited) rest  
        with Not_found ->  
          x:: aux (x::visited) (succ g x)  
  in aux [] [start];;
```

raises the error

```
File "test.ml", line 32, characters 17-18:
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         'a * int * 'b
```

which points to `if (tot [x])` where indeed `tot` expects a list of triples, but you have passed it an int list.

Also did you really mean to call `tot [x]`? It's not totaling anything; x is just a single node there.

Comment: I tried going backt to solve problem so i modified first bf_patg function to adapt is to work with triples, so the function tot will work correctly. (i updated the question).

Comment: did you try adding type annotations to everything? that should still help you find out what's going wrong